# How to undo something that i did with a .reg script? (The title may be confusing so just check the content of this post)

Tags: visual-studio-code, registry

*Please note i do not have ANY experience with .reg files, I was doing this because I found it in an article due to a problem I had with VSCode. (Link to it is below)*

So i have a .reg file containing the following code:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Open files
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with VS Code]
@="Open with VSCode"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe,0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with VS Code\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""
; This will make it appear when you right click ON a folder
; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\vscode]
@="Open Folder as VS Code Project"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\",0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\vscode\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""
; This will make it appear when you right click INSIDE a folder
; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\vscode]
@="Open Folder as VS Code Project"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\",0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\vscode\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%V\""
```

I got it from this [link](https://thisdavej.com/right-click-on-windows-folder-and-open-with-visual-studio-code/).

Now the problem is I already found a different way to solve the previous issue I had before this, and now I have no idea how to undo what I did with the current file I'm showing. Because I know it probably isn't as simple as just deleting the file.

**Can someone help me figure out how to undo what I did in the script?
I do not want the option in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8Lky.png) picture to be here anymore.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always compare your registry with another computer's registry entries and take the originals from the other computer (another computer with vsCode).

Use regedit and browse to the locations in our reg file on the other computer and then copy over the original values to the regedit on your computer.

You can also export the values from the other computer and import them to yours using .reg files.